# Grouping a VisualForce list by Account

Tags: visualforce, group-by

I have created a list in visualforce but it's quite boring. I would like to group by Account so it would look like

```
HgCapital
Month    Subject          Activity Date
Feb      blah blah blah   01/02/2015
Apr      blah blah blah   15/04/2015
Aug      blah blah blah   04/08/2015
```

Instead of

```
Month    Subject    Account    Activity Date
Feb      Blah blah  HgCapital  01/02/2015
```

I'm thinking this can be done in Visualforce and I tried creating nested pageBlocks to no avail.

Huge thanks in advance for your help.

APEX

```
public with sharing class FutureMeetings_CC {
    public List<Event> getFutureList()  {
        return [SELECT Id, AccountId, Subject, ActivityDate
                        FROM Event 
                        WHERE type='Meeting' AND ActivityDate > TODAY
                        AND AccountId  IN 
                            (select id FROM Account 
                                WHERE Status__c = 'Active Prospect')
                                ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC];


    }


}
```

VisualForce

```
<apex:page Controller="FutureMeetings_CC">

    <apex:pageBlock title="Future Meetings">

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!FutureList}" var="Meeting">

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Month</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM}">
                    <apex:param value="{!Meeting.ActivityDate}"/>
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.AccountId}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Subject</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.Subject}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Date</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.ActivityDate}"/>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added more detail. Can you actually share with us the data structure you are looping through? Are these `SObject` records? Some other form of data? How would they be grouped by `Account`? What is their relationship to it?

Comment: Sorry. I've added the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
public with sharing class FutureMeetings_CC {


     public List<Account> getFutureList(){

        List<Account> lst = [select id,Name,(SELECT Id, Subject, ActivityDate FROM Events 
                                          WHERE type='Meeting' AND ActivityDate > TODAY ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC) 
                               FROM Account WHERE Status__c = 'Active Prospect'];
         return lst;
     }
}
```

Page

```
<apex:page Controller="FutureMeetings_CC">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Future Meetings">

        <apex:repeat value="{!FutureList}" var="Account">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.Events}" var="Meeting">

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Month</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM}">
                    <apex:param value="{!Meeting.ActivityDate}"/>
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Subject</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.Subject}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Date</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.ActivityDate}"/>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
       </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Curious, why do you have public `set` for your properties? These do not seem like they should be writable from the page.

Comment: yes we can use without that

Comment: It's pretty easy to auto-pilot while creating properties and just give them public setters. Completely unnecessary, but there are a lot less callers involved in Apex than there are in traditional Java, so I find that devs tend to care less about visibility (beyond whether or not something should be global).

Comment: Yes but I think your intent as a developer is much more clear when you use private setters everywhere except where you want people interacting with your properties.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Added both option

Comment: @AdrianLarson I agree, just noting that you'll find in Apex a lot of SFDC devs simply don't bother. Not a great practice, but you'll see it a lot.

Comment: sorry @guys i don't usually follow this. Prev I had a same req so i just modified few things and Added as Ans. Now I removed my first ans

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would add some lazy loading so you do not need to run the query every time you access a property. The basic pattern looks like:

```
public List<Account> accounts
{
    get
    {
        if (accounts == null)
        {
            accounts = [SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE ...];
        }
        return accounts;
    }
    private set;
}
```

As @ratan mentioned, you can use a sub-query to get everything you need in one go:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Subject, ActivityDate FROM Events)
FROM Account WHERE ...
```

It might also be worth splitting out these tables into a `VisualForce Component`:

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="account" type="Account"
        description="Account for which to display events" />
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!account.Name}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.Events}" var="event">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:facet name="header">Month</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM}">
                    <apex:param value="{!event.ActivityDate}"/>
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!event.Subject}" />
            <apex:column value="{!event.ActivityDate}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:component>
```

Then your `VisualForce Page` markup would essentially boil down to:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="account">
        <c:EventsTable account="{!account}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlock>
```